# ZF1 Routing: Can route parameter defaults reference the URI variables?

Tags: zend-framework

If one of my routes inside my application.ini config file look like this:
resources.router.routes.internal.chains.params.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.internal.chains.params.route = "/:controller/:action/:id*"
resources.router.routes.internal.chains.params.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.internal.chains.params.defaults.action = "index"

Is there any way I can do something like this:
resources.router.routes.internal.chains.params.defaults.controllerAction = :controller-:action

Comment: So you just want the route to be `:controller-:action/:id`?

Comment: no it doesn't have to do with the routing, just the parameters that are injected into the request object based on the route.

Comment: Okay, yes, would probably need to be a controller plugin. I'm curious why you would want to do this though?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do this in a plugin.